# Create a loop to get 6 items from fullcalendar

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I am new to coldfusion and Mura and having a hard time to do the following: I was able to grab a single event from the fullcalendar. However, I am trying display underneath the calendar 6 events instead of 1. How and where would I add the cfloop to accomplish this? Here is the following code:

```
    <!--- Derived from: --->
<!--- Upcoming events --->
    <cffunction name="MultipleFeaturedEvents">
    <cfargument name="feedName" type="string" default="702771E7-155D-0201-11DF8865B175735F"/>
    <cfargument name="maxMonths" type="numeric" default="3" />
    <cfargument name="groupDailyEvents" default="true" />
    <cfscript>

        var rs = '';
        var subRS = '';
        var local = {};

        local.util = $.getCalendarUtility();
        local.rsItems = local.util.getCalendarItems(calendarid=arguments.feedName, start=Now(), end=DateAdd('m', val(4), Now()));


        var qoq = new Query();
        qoq.setDBType('query');
        qoq.setAttributes(rs=local.rsItems, maxRows=val(1));
        qoq.setSQL('
            SELECT *
            FROM rs
            ORDER BY displaystart ASC
        ');
        var qoqResult = qoq.execute().getResult();
        local.it = $.getBean('contentIterator').setQuery(qoqResult);

    </cfscript>
    <cfsavecontent variable="local.str">
        <cfoutput>
                <!---<div>#local.it.hasNext()#</div>--->
                <cfset local.item = local.it.next()>
                <!--- TODO: set a default image if no image is available --->
                <div class="hidden-xs col-md-2">
                    <p class="upcoming-events-image"><img src="#local.item.getImageURL()#" alt="#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getTitle())#"> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-4" id="featured-event">
                    <h3>Feature Event</h3>
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar fixIconCal"></i>
                    <!---#local.item.getDisplaystart()#--->
                    #LSDateFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStart'), "mmm d, yyyy")#
                    <cfquery dbtype="query" name="subRS1">
                        select *
                        from rsItems
                        where rsItems.contentid = <cfqueryparam value="#local.item.getValue('contentid')#" />
                    </cfquery>
                    <cfif subRS1.recordcount gt 1>
                        <!--- end date --->
                        <cfset enddate = ListLast(ValueList(subRS1.displaystop)) />
                        <cfif IsValid('date', enddate)>
                            - #LSDateFormat(enddate)#
                        </cfif>
                    </cfif>
                    <br />
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                    #timeFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStart'), "h:mm tt")# - #timeFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStop'), "h:mm tt")#
                    <br />
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                    #HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getMenuTitle())#
                    <!--- Summary --->
                    <div class="featured-event-summary">
                        <cfif Len(local.item.getValue('summary'))>
                        #local.item.getValue('summary')#
                        </cfif>
                    </div>
                </div>



        </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn local.str />
</cffunction>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have done the following to do the loop but it still is not working correctly. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but any help would be appreciated:

```
<cffunction name="MultipleFeaturedEvents">
    <cfargument name="feedName" type="string" default="702771E7-155D-0201-11DF8865B175735F"/>
    <cfargument name="maxMonths" type="numeric" default="3" />
    <cfargument name="groupDailyEvents" default="true" />
    <cfscript>

        var rs = '';
        var subRS = '';
        var local = {};

        local.util = $.getCalendarUtility();
        local.rsItems = local.util.getCalendarItems(calendarid=arguments.feedName, start=Now(), end=DateAdd('m', val(4), Now()));


        var qoq = new Query();
        qoq.setDBType('query');
        qoq.setAttributes(rs=local.rsItems, maxRows=val(1));
        qoq.setSQL('
            SELECT *
            FROM rs
            ORDER BY displaystart ASC
        ');
        var qoqResult = qoq.execute().getResult();
        local.it = $.getBean('contentIterator').setQuery(qoqResult);

    </cfscript>
    <cfsavecontent variable="local.str">
        <cfoutput>
        <cfset ctr= 1 />
            <cfloop condition="(local.it.hasNext()) AND (ctr LT 6)">
                <cfset local.item = local.it.next() />
                        <!--- TODO: set a default image if no image is available --->
                        <div class="hidden-xs col-md-2">
                            <p class="upcoming-events-image"><img src="#local.item.getImageURL()#" alt="#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getTitle())#"> </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-4" id="featured-event">
                            <h3>Feature Event</h3>
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar fixIconCal"></i>
                            <!---#local.item.getDisplaystart()#--->
                            #LSDateFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStart'), "mmm d, yyyy")#
                            <cfquery dbtype="query" name="subRS1">
                                select *
                                from rsItems
                                where rsItems.contentid = <cfqueryparam value="#local.item.getValue('contentid')#" />
                            </cfquery>
                            <cfif subRS1.recordcount gt 1>
                                <!--- end date --->
                                <cfset enddate = ListLast(ValueList(subRS1.displaystop)) />
                                <cfif IsValid('date', enddate)>
                                    - #LSDateFormat(enddate)#
                                </cfif>
                            </cfif>
                            <br />
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                            #timeFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStart'), "h:mm tt")# - #timeFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStop'), "h:mm tt")#
                            <br />
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                            #HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getMenuTitle())#
                            <!--- Summary --->
                            <div class="featured-event-summary">
                                <cfif Len(local.item.getValue('summary'))>
                                #local.item.getValue('summary')#
                                </cfif>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <cfset ctr++ />
            </cfloop>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn local.str />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: "not working correctly" is rather vague, don't you think.  I also suggest that you troubleshoot your function with ColdFusion only before you try it with javascript.

Comment: @DanBracuk Sorry for being vague. What happens is when I run the code, it will only display one event rather then 6 events. Not sure why it is doing that

Comment: @DanBracuk I thought by adding a cfloop and doing something like '<cfset ctr=1> <cfloop ><cfset ctr eq 1>....<cfset ctr++></cfloop>' would generate 6 events but it just generated only one event